# Using When and Less then in Django DRF?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to check where a number is `GreaterThan` another number in the `request.data` and set the value if condition is true.

```
ExampleModel.objects.filter(
                        tic=request.data['tic']).update(last_high=When(GreaterThan(F('last_high'), request.data['high']), then=0))
```

Error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "WHEN": syntax error

I am not sure how to proceed from here, trying to understand the documentation but I can't seem to find why it won't work.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

Comment: then=0 must be inside the When parenthesis

Comment: @Alombaros, sorry about that, the then=0 is inside the When parenthesis. Fixed it in the question. I forgot the field I was updating in the original question, edited.

Comment: I am trying to check whether the `last_high`, let's assume its 10 right now, is greater than `request.data['high'], if it is then I want to set `last_high` to 0.

If `last_high` > `high` then `last_high` value to be updated to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could something like that do the trick ?

```
ExampleModel.objects.filter(tic=request.data['tic'], last_high__gt=request.data['high']).update(last_high=0)
```

**EDIT:**
After some back and forth in the comments section, the right answer would be

```
ExampleModel.objects.filter(tic=request.data['tic']).update(last_high=Case(When(LessThan(F('high_price'), request.data['high']), then=Value(101)), default=Value(0)))
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, I am still checking. I want to include various conditions after this. For example, if the `last_high` is `None`. The main reason to try and understand the `When` statement is to be able to add more statements later.

Comment: I am not sure that When() can be used without a Case(). I guess you could do Case(When(..., then=0), When(...), default=F('last_high'))

Comment: It worked! Please change your answer so I can accept it. `ExampleModel.objects.filter(tic=request.data['tic']).update(last_high=Case(When(LessThan(F('high_price'), request.data['high']), then=Value(101)), default=Value(0)))`